# window.history.go(-1) is not working in ie 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

window.history.go(-1) is not working in IE6

Any Other solution for back button which can work in IE6.

Comment: IE9 doesn't supprt the HTML5 history API. What makes you think IE6 will?

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there though, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: @Raynos `history.go()` method isn't part of HTML5 History API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.history.go(-1) is not working in ie 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745108/window-history-go-1-is-not-working-in-ie-6)

Comment: @duri [WHATWG spec history API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface)

Comment: @Raynos Only `pushState()` and `replaceState()` methods were added by HTML5. The `go()` method existed before HTML5 and is supported even in IE6 (the support is obviously buggy, though). This has nothing to do with HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has trouble with window.history.go(). It works on regular links like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</a>
```

But some others won't work. You could try this:

```
<button onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</button>
```

But I'm not quite sure if that would work. You could also show a button for all other browsers and a link for IE:

```
<button id='backButton' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</button>
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('backButton').style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    <a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</a>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have try as stated above. But it even dont work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.history.back()`

Comment: it's well know that for back button , there are two ways 1) window.history.back() 2) history.go(-1) , but both are not working in ie6. is any one able to suggest , any other option to get this  ??

Comment: are you sure there's a page to go back *to*?